# When I was in trouble he borrowed me money. When I was in trouble he lent me money

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> When I was in trouble he **borrowed** me money.
>   When I was in trouble he **lent** me money.

What is the difference between them? 
Which one is correct?

Comment: Stick with the latter and avoid the former.

Comment: @J.R. Ah, but why?

Comment: "borrow, lend" in the search field gives 9 results. And research in online dictionaries should make the difference between the two verbs clear.

Comment: speaking usage is usually `loaned` not `lent` maybe not grammatically correct but what you hear more often

Comment: One thing to beware of is that even native English speakers often use "borrow" to mean "lend" but only in informal, colloquial speech (experienced in Minnesota, US; Wales, Surrey and Yorkshire, UK). Personally it grates on me, but I anticipate this usage becoming accepted over time, with language creep.

Answer (score 11):

**Meaning**

These two verbs *lend* and *borrow* often cause confusion for learners. The main reason is that many languages use just one verb for both of these meanings

The verb *lend* is like the verb ***give***. It means to give temporarily, not permanently.

The verb *borrow* is more like the verb ***take***. If you borrow something you are taking it, but temporarily, not permanently.

---

**Grammar**

The  verb *lend* has the same grammar as the verb *give*. It takes an Indirect Object (the person your giving the thing to) and a Direct Object (the thing that you are giving):

- He gave me a pen.
- He lent me a pen.

The verb *borrow* has the same grammar as the verb *take*. It normally takes a Direct Object (the thing being taken) and it sometimes also takes a preposition phrase headed by the preposition *from*:

- I took a pen from him.
- I borrowed a pen from him.

---

**The Original Poster's question**

> 1. *When I was in trouble he borrowed me money. (ungrammatical)
> 2. When I was in trouble he lent me money.

Sentence (1) is incorrect for two reasons. Firstly the subject of the sentence *he* is giving the money, not taking it. Therefore we need the verb *lend* not the verb *borrow*.

Secondly the grammar in sentence (1) is problematic. The verb *borrow* cannot take an Indirect Object. We can't say "borrow me" in standard English.

Sentence (2) is, of course, perfectly fine. The poster could make a similar sentence with the word *borrow*, but this would need a different Subject:

> When I was in trouble I borrowed money from him.

However, this sentence has a completely different feeling to it.

---

[**Note:**

1. This is the first installment of a post. The second installment will be much more complicated and will show how *He borrowed me some money* could be correct but not if *me* is a normal Object.
2. It might be worth noting that in some regional varieties of English we *can* use the verb *borrow* with the same grammar and meaning as *lend*, but this does not happen in standard Englishes like Southern Standard British English or General American.]

Comment: You could be a slave talking to someone nicknamed _money_ :)

Comment: In non-standard English, "he borrowed me money" might also be possible with "me" as a possessive pronoun :) But that's pragmatically unlikely in the context of "when I was in trouble."

Comment: @sumelic Quite right!

Comment: If you're rewriting, will you address whether "he borrowed me money" could be read as "he borrowed money (from others) on my behalf" or "he borrowed money that he then lent to me"?

Answer (score 5):

Although the above answers give lots of details, I prefer the below explanation...

> **Lend** is equivalent to **Throw**, or **Give**
>
> You lend money **to** someone. (Past tense: loaned or sometimes lent)

And

> **Borrow** is equivalent to **Catch**, or **Receive**
>
> You borrow something **from** them. (Past tense: borrowed)

Note that you can borrow something for someone, but not to them. Like I could catch a ball for you (when a third person throws it), but I could not catch it to you.

Comment: +1 I really love your  *throw* and *catch* mnemonic. I've been using *give* and *take* for years but it doesn't distinguish the two actions clearly enough (obviously if you speak English the difference is clear, but .... so what?). Another I've used is ***b**eggars **b**orrow* but that's rubbish for a thousand reasons. Thanks. Every bone of my teaching intuition tells me that *throw* and *catch* will be more successful for students. That is if they can remember which is which. Maybe they won't be able to, but it's worth a shot!

Comment: At least if they know that's the distinction, they won't confuse the two, even if they get the wrong one :)

Answer (score 2):

They mean different! In second, he gives you money **directly**. In the first sentence, he **does it** for you. While the latter is pretty clear, the former is tricky. Let me explain the first.

*"He bought me a doll"* - *he* does the action of 'buying'. And 'you' are the one who's receiving. *"He borrowed me money"* - *he* does the action of 'borrowing' money (but here **from** someone), and again, you are the receiver.

> He buys a doll. He buys it for me = He bought me a doll 
>  He *borrows some money*. He borrows it for me  = He borrowed me some money

Think of A, B, and C.

If B asks C for a calculator **for** A, the B actually borrows the gadget **for** A *from* C.

> A: I want to borrow a calculator from C but I'm feeling shy 
>  B: No worries, I do that for you.
>
> B: Hey C, will you give me your calculator **for** A as he's feeling shy? 
>  C: Ah, why not. Here it is!

Here, B borrowed A the calculator. Said that, A can say **"When I needed it, B borrowed me a calculator"**

I found a result from COCA similar to what I said in my comment -

> My folks couldn't afford a guitar, so my dad ***borrowed me*** a mandolin one time, and I was just learning to play it pretty good and *the guy that **he borrowed it from** wanted it back.*

'you' are an indirect object receiving something in both of your sentences.

So,

Which one correct - IMO, both.
Do they mean the same - No, they don't.

Comment: _Someone doesn't borrow something to someone, but from someone, as in "I borrowed her calculator."_ (from [10 Common Grammar Mistakes Even Smart People Make](http://www.inc.com/christina-desmarais/10-common-grammar-mistakes-even-smart-people-make.html). In other words, you can borrow his money, but, object or no object, he ***can't*** borrow you money – not without being grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Want to understand this further... will do my homework. Deleting as of now. @J.R.

Comment: @J.R. added. I think it's possible.

Comment: @J.R. Sir, I would like to know your thoughts regarding answer to this tricky question.

Comment: @MaulikV How many such examples did you find in COCA? I think not very many, am I right? Here is the search I used to verify your claim: http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=41225335.

Comment: I got the example to what exactly i want to say. The example I made and the example I found. Who said it's *common*; it's not. **But**, it's possible. And I stand by my words (hence 'undeleted') @DamkerngT.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Will you be happy if I add a sentence - *"I just found an example quite similar to my own example"*. Even further, what if I *remove* COCA? Why do you focus on the example rather than what I am trying to say?

Comment: I pointed out some issues with your example because you used it to back your claim. You *assert* that the usage is correct. (Let's be clear without having to use a vague term such as *possible*; you wrote "the meaning is the same" anyway.) This is not the first time you make this kind of assertion. It's easy for everyone nowadays to search things here and there and then claim something. But does that make it correct? -- Also, this is not about me being happy, but I hope to see high rep users such as you and me and others would be more careful with our answers.

Comment: I'm pretty concerned about my answer and *that's why* I **made** an example after pondering over the topic. @DamkerngT. [Software says move to chat]!

Comment: @DamkerngT. The problem is old bean that the sentence could be completely grammatical., couldn't it? For example, "If you go to the library could you borrow me a book please?". Or "If you haven't got any money I could borrow you some from the bank".

Comment: @MaulikV I think the problem is that you aren't taking into account that the real issue for the OP is probably the difference in meaning and grammar between *lend* and *borrow*. So even though your examples are grammatical, they're slightly misleading because they could lead learners to think that it's acceptable to use the first example, when the second is reuqired. Why? Because your answer ducks this issue, that's all. Having said that your examples *are* grammatical.

Comment: The mandolin example is deceptive. In "my dad borrowed me a mandolin", the speaker is **not** getting the mandolin from his dad. The implication is: _My dad borrowed a mandolin **[for] me [from someone else]**._ My assertion is backed up by the rest of that passage: _the guy that he borrowed it from wanted it back_. (P.S. to @RuchirM - If you want my answer to this question, read the answer provided by Araucaria below. I have just upvoted it, and my answer wouldn't really provide any new information.)

Comment: A good answer - I hadn't previously considered there might be cases where this might be grammatically correct. Not what the OP meant, certainly, but a valuable answer in an "it is only correct if you use it this way, otherwise it's an error" way.

Answer (score 1):

The direct object for 'borrow' and 'lend' should be an object/material thing. You cannot use it in the first sentence, unless you change 'me' to 'my', but that will make the sense of the sentence wrong.

Also, when it comes to money/financially related terms, 'lend' is the proper verb to use. Borrow is usually used for other objects/material things.